# Every automorphism a of a finite field with characteristic p $\mathbb{F}$ we have that $a(r)=r$ $\forall r\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Tags: finite-fields, automorphism-group

Hi i need to prove the following:

$\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field with characteristic p.Show that for every automorphism a of the field $\mathbb{F}$ we have that $a(r)=r$  $\forall r\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

I am a little confused on how to start it,I know there is a simiral prove in galois theory for fields with characteristic 0 that  automorphisms have fixed points in $\mathbb{Q}$ but I dont understant how to do it generally.Thanks

Comment: By definition $a(1)=1$, and $a(1+1)=a(1)+a(1)$... Can you take on?

Comment: Any automorphism will fix the prime field elementwise. So $\alpha(x)=x$ for all $x\in \Bbb F_p$.

Comment: thanks a lot .I think I got it